# Query Processing at backend (I/O on disk)

Tags: postgresql, profiler, performance, postgresql-performance

I have a table with 100k rows created on PostgreSQL 9.3

```
create table demo_bbb
(
  id numeric NOT NULL,
  code_bbb character varying,  
  column_02 character varying,  
  column_03 character varying,  
  column_04 character varying,  
  column_05 character varying,  
  column_06 character varying,  
  column_07 character varying,  
  column_08 character varying,  
  column_09 character varying,  
  column_10 character varying,  
  CONSTRAINT demo_bbb_pk PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

Here's my test (each query is run 3 times):

```
(1) select id from demo_bbb b ;         -- database query time: ~26ms
(2) select column_10 from demo_bbb b ;  -- database query time: 46ms, 48ms, 51ms
(3) select column_05 from demo_bbb b ;  -- database query time: 37ms, 38 ms, 45ms
(4) select * from demo_bbb b ;          -- database query time: 28ms, 32ms, 37ms
```

Result: Average time of (4) < time of (2), (3)  (**32ms < 45 ms**)

Explain analyze:

```
(1) "Seq Scan on demo_bbb b  (cost=0.00..4425.00 rows=100000 width=6) (actual time=0.008..22.088 rows=100000 loops=1)"
(2) "Seq Scan on demo_bbb b  (cost=0.00..4425.00 rows=100000 width=24) (actual time=0.008..38.702 rows=100000 loops=1)"
(3) "Seq Scan on demo_bbb b  (cost=0.00..4425.00 rows=100000 width=24) (actual time=0.008..32.098 rows=100000 loops=1)"
(4) "Seq Scan on demo_bbb b  (cost=0.00..4425.00 rows=100000 width=232) (actual time=0.007..17.702 rows=100000 loops=1)"
```

I am curious to know what happened but I can not understand. Could you give me some explanations of how these queries did ?

Note: I traced these queries by using SQL Profiler [(download from Enterprisedb)](http://www.enterprisedb.com/downloads/postgres-postgresql-downloads)

Comment: Show `EXPLAIN (BUFFERS, ANALYZE)` output for each query. See http://dba.stackexchange.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info for details.

Comment: @CraigRinger: thanks. I modified my post.

Comment: Well, that pretty much confirms you're seeing caching effects then. Getting faster as the row width gets wider? Got to be caching. BTW, you should really be seeing an index-only scan on (1). Are you on an old PostgreSQL version? (You should always include your version in questions).

Comment: Ok, I am testing on PostgreSQL v9.3 . With table demo_bbb, (4) have more columns than (2),(3) so I think (4) have to cache data more than (2), (3). But why database query time of (4) is less than (2),(3) .

Comment: @CraigRinger As a heuristic to cut down on planning time, the planner won't even consider using an index unless the index can theoretically contribute some selectively.  If the planner never considers the index, it can't realize that an index-only scan might be a good idea.  You can possibly get an index-only scan by adding `where id is not null` to the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty much a WAG because you haven't shown `EXPLAIN (BUFFERS, OUTPUT)` data, but:

```
select id from demo_bbb b; -- database query time: ~26ms
```

If you're on 9.2 or newer this probably did an index-only scan on the unique index used to implement the primary key constraint. Given the latter times that's the most likely case; if it'd done a seqscan (as it would on older versions) you'd have got faster results from later queries.

```
select column_10 from demo_bbb b ;  -- database query time: 46ms, 48ms, 51ms
select column_05 from demo_bbb b ;  -- database query time: 37ms, 38 ms, 45ms
select * from demo_bbb b ;          -- database query time: 28ms, 32ms, 37ms
```

These are likely to be doing seqscans, and possibly out-of-line TOAST fetching.

The different times will be partly due to caching effects, possibly partly offset by the need to read in more out-of-line TOAST data when you select more columns.

PostgreSQL uses two levels of caching - the operating system's disk cache, and its own `shared_buffers`. Both are block caches. It does not have a query result cache.

For more information see the PostgreSQL manual and the existing resources about PostgreSQL benchmarking, tuning, caching behaviour, etc.

Comment: I think it is because of caching effects. When I restart database server and run these queries in the first time , time of (4) > (3) > (2) > (1) .